# How to select two elements from list and do math on them in Python?

Tags: python

I have a file containing several start and end-positions of a sequence (MANY!) and I want to select the start and end positions, subtract the end position from the start to get the length of a particular sequence, and then randomly place that sequence somewhere between the smallest start number and largest end number.  Don't know if that makes any sense.....

However here is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import random
import math
import re

file = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')

list = []

for line in file:
    if line.startswith('G'):
        continue

    else:
        pos = re.split('\s', line)
        list.append(pos[0])
        list.append(pos[1])
        list = map(int, list)
        for i in list:
            #ldom = (i:i+1)-i + 1 
print randrange(1, 3000000000, ldom)

file.close()
```

The '#' line is the one I'm having problems with. I have a list where each element represents either a start or end position, list[0] represents a start and list[1] an end position. I just don't know how to subtract list[1] from list[0], and add 1 to that number....list comprehensions only seem to work on non-specific elements or all.

Comment: Please provide the sample data you are working

Comment: Use len(list) to get the length of the list

Comment: Also, consider naming the list other than list... why?

Comment: Err no - it doesn't make sense... Some simple sample input and desired output might help though

Comment: Sorry.....the file looks like this: 123   456, newline, 789  885, newline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an ipython-interpreter example of splitting a line on whitespace (as noted in docs for [str.split()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), whitespace is the default separator), converting items to integers (via `map(int, ...)`, and then [zipping](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) into pairs:

```
In [127]: line='0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16'

In [128]: zip(*[iter(map(int, line.split()))]*2)
Out[128]: [(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7), (8, 9), (10, 11), (12, 13), (14, 15)]
```

You can set some variable, say `bounds`, to the zip expression, and then iterate on list `bounds` to do whatever it is you need to do to the “particular sequence”.
For example:

```
In [131]: bounds = zip(*[iter(map(int, line.split()))]*2)

In [132]: for lo, hi in bounds: print 'lo:', lo, '\thi:', hi, '\tdelta:', hi-lo+1
lo: 0   hi: 1   delta: 2
lo: 2   hi: 3   delta: 2
lo: 4   hi: 5   delta: 2
lo: 6   hi: 7   delta: 2
lo: 8   hi: 9   delta: 2
lo: 10  hi: 11  delta: 2
lo: 12  hi: 13  delta: 2
lo: 14  hi: 15  delta: 2
```

Comment: I added a `for lo, hi in bounds:` example

Answer (score 0):

> I just don't know how to subtract list[1] from list[0], and add 1 to that number....

I don't know if that helps, but **always try to keep it simple bro**:

```
ldom = list[0] - list[1] + 1
```

This should do, provided that the objects you operate on are a kind of number and that you **remove** the iteration upon the list objects (`for i in list`)

Comment: I tried this but it complains about not being able to "assign to operator" :(

Comment: I see what the problem is. It may have an issue with the parentheses, considering it a tuple.

Comment: @user1882385 Try it now and tell me if it works now. If it is possible.

Comment: By removing the parentheses? But how will it now which element to subtract? :O

Comment: It does with `list[0]` and `list[1]`. The parentheses were there to ensure that the additions are performed correctly, but were not really needed. May even be the issue in this case, as the parentheses are the `tuple` operator.